# Error al instalar pyo en Python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-3.8

Al tratar de instalar pyo 1.0.1 a través de pip, obtengo el siguiente error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Users\Gabriela\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-f3_g3cog\\pyo\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-f3_g3cog\\pyo\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-pip-egg-info-b10qs5vh'
     cwd: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-f3_g3cog\pyo\
Complete output (5 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-f3_g3cog\pyo\setup.py", line 206, in <module>
    [os.path.join(data_files_common_path, f) for f in os.listdir(data_files_common_path) if f.endswith(".dll")]),
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada: 'win32dlls\\win32_pyo_data_files_common'
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Verifiqué el contenido del paquete y parece que no me falta nada, creo que el programa está buscando en la ruta equivocada pero no sé como solucionarlo.